# How to input Values in Google Maps using Python/Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I cannot use send keys correctly to input values.

I would like to be able to insert text into the text box.

Tried 2 different methods

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/.../Documents/chromedriver')

driver.get('http://codepad.org/')
text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('textarea')
text_area.send_keys("This text is send using Python code.")


from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/.../Documents/chromedriver')
driver.get( 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir///@36.0667234,-115.1059052,15z')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@placeholder='Choose starting point, or click on the map...']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@placeholder='Choose starting point, or click on the map...']").clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@placeholder='Choose starting point, or click on the map...']").send_keys("New York")
```

Put a value into the fields i am trying to put the values in

Comment: What error are you getting?both code works fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that you can use, which will wait for the element to present and then set the value in the input box.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//input[@class='tactile-searchbox-input'])[1]"))).send_keys("new york")
```

BTW you need below imports in order to work with explicit wait used in the above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```